# Disable keyboard in UIwebView textField in swift

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I wrote a webApp in `html/css/js` using another text editor, then copied the text over to the relevant files in an existing Xcode project.

The project runs inside a webView alright "left image", but when I click inside a text field "right image" part of the stock keyboard covers the 2 bottom buttons.

I expected to see a fully fledged keyboard, but I really would like to disable it all together, because I will provide my own later.

How to disable the stock keyboard when a webView textField is tapped in this case?

Swift 2.1 and Xcode 7.2.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mainWV: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //load a file
    let localfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("index", withExtension: "html");
    let myRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: localfilePath!);
    mainWV.loadRequest(myRequest);

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: same issue. Something new about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try make use of `UIView` superclass (superclass of `UIWebView` as well ass super-super of `UITextField`) property `.userInteractionEnabled`:

```
myWebViewTextField.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Alternatively, if this is not what you're looking for, try the property `.enabled` from superclass `UIControl` of `UITextField`:

```
myWebViewTextField.enabled = false
```

---

> `UIView.userInteractionEnabled` *Property*
>
> A Boolean value that determines whether user events are ignored and
>   removed from the event queue.

From the [Language Reference for `UIVIew`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/userInteractionEnabled).

> `UIControl.enabled` *Property*
>
> A Boolean value that determines whether the receiver is enabled.

From the [Language Reference for `UIControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/enabled).

Comment: The textField is not created on the storyBoard so there is no reference to it in the code. It is created in the html page being loaded by the webView, i.e. myWebViewTextField.<property> = boolean is not possible. Please see update code snippet.